# I can't receiving notifications when the app is closed or swiped away on huawei device?

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

I'm using onsignal notifications with my flutter app,I've tested my app on three Samsunge devices and notifcations working perfectly in all these devices when the app on foreground, background, and also when I swiped it away.
after that I tested the app on huawei device which using EMUI 9.0.1 Os
the notifications only works if the app is active or on background
if I swiped it away I can't receiving any notifications.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been struggling with this for a long time. I'll post my code for setting onesignal below

```
Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
if (!mounted) return;

OneSignal.shared.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose, OSLogLevel.none);

OneSignal.shared.setRequiresUserPrivacyConsent(true);
OneSignal.shared.consentGranted(true);


var settings = {
OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
OSiOSSettings.promptBeforeOpeningPushUrl: true
};



OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((notification) {
this.setState(() {
print('Notifiaction received');
});
});

OneSignal.shared
.setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
this.setState(() {
newUrl = result.notification.payload.additionalData['url'].toString();
});
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  WebNotification(newUrl)));

});
// NOTE: Replace with your own app ID from https://www.onesignal.com
await OneSignal.shared
.init("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx", iOSSettings: settings);

OneSignal.shared
.setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);
OneSignal.shared.inFocusDisplayType();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a service extension. Take a look at our docs on [Background Notifications](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/silent-notifications). Also, consider [Notification Behavior](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/how-notifications-work) when designing your implementation

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply, it means I should write native code right ?

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you sue latest version of onesignal
2. for huwaii use HMS if possible ( onesignal support HMS )
3. 

In your root build.gradle, under buildscript, add the following 2 new lines to your existing repositories and dependencies sections

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal 
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.8, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
```

Add the following to the top of your app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

4. you need  to make user add your app to ignore battry optmztion in huwaii it is (protacted app )
   in flutter you can make button and attach it to the app setting  ( use these plugin https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings)