# Unable to receive notification from onesignal when app is closed from background flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

this question is duplicate to [I can't receiving notifications when the app is closed or swiped away on huawei device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841853/i-cant-receiving-notifications-when-the-app-is-closed-or-swiped-away-on-huawei) I have tried solution there, but still didn't get notification when I close my app, is there another thing that I am missed?
here is android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.onesignal_notif"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours long, finally my app can received background notifications and enter the apps once clicking on the notifications bar !

Just don't copy all the code section here to your project https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions#android-notification-service-extension. You need only the code below to make your background notifications works in flutter.

```java
package com.companyName.applicationName;

import android.content.Context;
import com.onesignal.OSNotification;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationReceivedEvent;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal.OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class NotificationServiceExtension implements OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler {
    @Override
    public void remoteNotificationReceived(Context context, OSNotificationReceivedEvent notificationReceivedEvent) {
        OSNotification notification = notificationReceivedEvent.getNotification();
        notificationReceivedEvent.complete(notification);
    }
}
```

Then in Manifest.xml add below meta data in application not activity tag.

```xml
<application>
  <activity/>
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationServiceExtension"
    android:value="com.companyName.applicationName.NotificationServiceExtension" />
</application>
```

In app/build.gradle i use this version of onesignal `implementation 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.14.0'`.

On `flutter 3.12.0` & `onesignal_flutter: ^3.5.1`.

I also replied in github [issues/618](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/618#issuecomment-1662572193).